# TestCafe Typescript - how to assert the value of a disabled html input element?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

TestCafe Typescript - how to assert the value of a disabled HTML input element?

The element is disabled to avoid interaction by the end user. However, I would like to check that this element contains the expected value.

```
example
  public async checksomething(text: string) {
    const inputElement = this.inputSelector();
    await t
      .click(this.someDiv())
      .expect(inputElement().value)
      .contains(text);
  }
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code? What is the result? What _specific_ error or test failure message do you get?

Comment: @AlexWayne Thanks for asking ... the err ->  1) Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree. I suppose it is because the element is disabled.

Comment: Disabled for field still exist in the DOM tree. So it sounds like you are trying to find something that isn't actually there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your usage scenario in the following sample:

```
<input type="text" value="12345" disabled="disabled"/>
```

```
async function checksomething (t, text) {
    const inputElement = Selector('input');
    await t
        .expect(inputElement().value)
        .contains(text);
}

test(`test`, async t => {
    await checksomething(t, '12345');
});
```

Everything works as expected. There is no error.
Please take a look at the `this.someDiv` element. Check if it is visible.
If it does not help, please share your sample to reproduce the issue on my machine.